# Objective-C and Preemptive Authentication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, apache, authentication

I am trying to get data from WebService for my Ipad App.

To do that, I am using a NSURLConnection with NSMutableURLRequest.

Web Services are published on Apache-Coyote 1.1 with Preemptive Basic Authentication, but I don't know how to send my credentials from Objective-C.

Anybody knows how can I set my user/password in Objective-C to log my clients with the Apache premptive authentication system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

In order to set the creds yourself, you'll need to be able to base64 encode the username and password and set the appropriate header.  Matt Gallagher, from Cocoa With Love, has a great post on [how to add a category to `NSData`](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) to easily do this.

```
NSString* username = @"username";
NSString* password = @"password";

NSString* encodedUsername = [[username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];
NSString* encodedPassword = [[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourUrl.com/"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString* headerValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@:%@", encodedUsername, encodedPassowrd];
[request addValue:@"Authorization" forHTTPHeaderField:headerValue];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

As with all use of credentials, please make sure you are doing this all over HTTPS because these credentials are essentially being passed in clear text.

Comment: The didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge delegate is not being called never with the preemptive system. (I tried with a .net webservice with basic authentication first, and the delegate worked fine)

Comment: @gabriel mendez - Updated to set the creds with the request.

Comment: I think the header should be something like:

NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString*)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password];  
    
NSString *encodedLoginData = [Base64 encode:[loginString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
       
NSString headerValue = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", encodedLoginData]; 

Now is working like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielMendez - You are right. The answer should be edited with your suggestion. The current way of generating header value is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framework, [which makes preemptive Basic authentication requests simple](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#presenting_credentials_before_the_server_asks_for_them):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setAuthenticationScheme:(NSString *)kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic]; /** preemptively present credentials **/
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error)
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
```

And, yes, you definitely want to do Basic authentication over SSL (i.e. via some `https://...` URL).

Comment: I would recommend against using synchronous requests.

Comment: I used the `-startSynchronous` method to demonstrate the request. It is fairly simple to do asynchronous requests with `ASIHTTPRequest`: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_an_asynchronous_request